# Python appending a list to dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from a stata file and I would like to add a new column to it which has a numeric list as an entry for each row. How can one accomplish this? I have been trying assignment but its complaining about index size.

I tried initiating a new column of strings (also tried integers) and tried something like this but it didnt work.

```
testdf['new_col'] = '0'
testdf['new_col'] = testdf['new_col'].map(lambda x : list(range(100)))
```

[image]

Here is a toy example resembling what I have:

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'start_val': [1,7,9,10], 'end_val' : [3,11, 12,15]}
testdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

[image]

This is what I would like to have:

```
data2 = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'start_val': [1,7,9,10], 'end_val' : [3,11, 12,15], 'list' : [[1,2,3],[7,8,9,10,11],[9,10,11,12],[10,11,12,13,14,15]]}
testdf2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
```

[image]

My final goal is to use explode on that "list" column to duplicate the rows appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this bit of code:

```
testdf['list'] = pd.Series(np.arange(i, j) for i, j in zip(testdf['start_val'], 
                                                            testdf['end_val']+1))
testdf
```

Output:

```
   col_1 col_2  start_val  end_val                      list
0      3     a          1        3                 [1, 2, 3]
1      2     b          7       11         [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
2      1     c          9       12           [9, 10, 11, 12]
3      0     d         10       15  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Let's use comprehension and zip with a `pd.Series` constructor and `np.arange` to create the lists.

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you!

Comment: @Amatya You're welcome.   Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd stick to using the apply function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'start_val': [1,7,9,10], 'end_val' : [3,11, 12,15]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['range'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.arange(row['start_val'], row['end_val']+1), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col_1 col_2  start_val  end_val                     range
0      3     a          1        3                 [1, 2, 3]
1      2     b          7       11         [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
2      1     c          9       12           [9, 10, 11, 12]
3      0     d         10       15  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do it using Apply! Really appreciate being taught many ways of doing stuff.